# How to bring a collection from UserModel to PatientModel using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

After I get the data from the base I need to bring it from model UserModel to the model PatientModel. I do it this way:

```
var _patients = patients.Select(p => new MyPatientModel
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            PatientEmail = p.Email,
            PatientFirstName = p.FirstName,
            PatientSecondName = p.SecondName,
            PatientThirdName = p.ThirdName,
        });
        return _patients;
```

but I need to do the same task using AutoMapper. I initialized these models in Startup so:

```
config.CreateMap<MyPatientModel, User>();
```

Please help solve this problem

Comment: you could rename the `MyPatientModel` properties to be `Email` instead of `PatientEmail`, `FirstName` instead of `PatientFirstName`, etc. and you won't need any custom mapping configuration set up. seems redundant to have all of your `MyPatientModel` fields prefixed with `Patient`

Answer (score 1):

Just use your types:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Patient, MyPatientModel>()
    .ForMember(myP => myP.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Id))
    .ForMember(myP => myP.PatientEmail, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Email))
    .ForMember(myP => myP.PatientFirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.FirstName))
    .ForMember(myP => myP.PatientSecondName, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.SecondName))
    .ForMember(myP => myP.PatientThirdName, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.ThirdName))
    );

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
List<MyPatientModel> myPatientList = mapper.Map<List<Patient>, List<MyPatientModel>>(patients);
```

Comment: but I have error mapping types. First param must be `IQueryable<Patient>`, otherwise patients cannot convert type, and second param I try `List<MyPatientModel>>`, `IList<MyPatientModel>>`, `ICollection<MyPatientModel>>`, but in all of these cases I have a error mapping types... What may be the reason?

Comment: @senjust according to automapper [documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html) you can not use IQueriable as a Source. But it will be the other question then.

Comment: @senjust it could also be error somewhere else, but it is hard to find from your example. You have to put everything into example so that anyone can get it, run it and see an error.